# Visualize extra info on plotly scatterplot when moving the cursor on marker

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Given the following toy `pd.DataFrame` :

```
    x   y  info
0  10   5    10
1  20  13    20
2  30  64    30
3  40  56    40
4  50  75    50
5  60  44    60
6  70  31    70
```

I want to visualize the extra `info` column when approaching a marker with the cursor. This is **not** related to any extra dimension, or anything that is supposed to be plotted, or neither has to appear directly into the plot. It is just an extra info I would like to visualize. For now I have just used the code

```
px.scatter(dataframe, 
            x='x,
            y='y'
         )
```

producing the result:

[image]

I just want the `'info'` being displayed under `'x'` and `'y'`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that with the code below:

```
## Import Libraries
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
    
## Create the Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
                   'y': [5, 13,  64, 56, 75, 44, 31],
                   'info': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]})

## The Plot 
layout = dict(plot_bgcolor='white',
              margin=dict(t=20, l=20, r=20, b=20),
              xaxis=dict(title='X',
                         range=[0, 100],
                         linecolor='#d9d9d9',
                         showgrid=False,
                         mirror=True),
              yaxis=dict(title='Y',
                         range=[0, 100],
                         linecolor='#d9d9d9',
                         showgrid=False,
                         mirror=True))

data = go.Scatter(x=df['x'],
                  y=df['y'],
                  text=df['info'],
                  textposition='bottom center',
                  textfont=dict(color='#E58606'),
                  mode='markers+text',
                  marker=dict(color='#5D69B1', size=8),
                  )

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

### Update with Mode

You could use `mode = markers` in your code to get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I was asking for. I don't want the `info` column to be displayed as text near the markers. This because in the real experiment I'm conducting I have a lot of markers and making those labels appearing would make the whole thing pretty confusing.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that changing the `mode` parameter to `mode = markers` does the job! many thanks! Could you update the answer by adding this comment?